# Is it possible to browse/search uploaded images?

Tags: feature-request, search

Is it possible to search uploaded images, for example type 'pie chart' and see the images connected to those posts?

Comment: If you're willing to do ~100 at a time you can use the StackExchange API (see [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers) and use `filter=withbody`). Then you can pull out image tags. You can also do that for a specific user with [users/{ids}/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users). I have a service connection lying around on the site that might help with this too. You can also use [this .mx dump of answer metadata](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.datasets/stack_exchange_data/answers/mmaAnswers.mx) as a starting point for searches.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use Google I guess. Try to search like this

```
pie chart site:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/
```

Comment: Yes, that only shows a small subset.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, [halirutan has provided the most effective way to search for image using Google](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2355/27904).

For SE's own tools, no, it's not really possible since images are stored just as that, image files. There's no metadata that describes if an image is a pie chart or anything else.

If users properly describe the alternative text on image markdown as "pie chart", e.g.

```
![example of pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ey1.jpg)
```

then it's possible to search for that using [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/892032/search-posts-based-on-images-alt-text?AltText=pie+chart) (as of writing, there's none). However, SEDE is updated each week.